# ASP.Net Postback event not getting selected value

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am populating an ASP.Net Dropdown list with values from an Ajax call Json Response using the code below.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/SelectMoveToFund",
            data: JSON.stringify(params),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $('select').select2('destroy');
                var ddl = $("#" + fundId);

                ddl.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Please select</option>');
                $.each(data.d, function () {
                    ddl.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
                });
                $('select').select2();

            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log("error :" + data);
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

This works and populates the targets dropdown list that is held in a datagrid on an ASP.Net Webforms page.

The problem I am having is when the pages posts back and im iterating through each row of the datagrid, its not passing me the value of the selected item in the list.

```
 For Each item As DataGridItem In dgUnsuitableSwitch.Items
                    Dim ddlFund As DropDownList = DirectCast(item.FindControl("ddlFund"), DropDownList)

 Next
```

The Datagrid is made up like this and part of it is populated from datatables where data is known, the rest is made up of customer information.

```
<asp:DataGrid runat="server" CssClass="tab table table-bordered table-striped table-hover " ID="dgUnsuitableSwitch" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Fund Name" HeaderText="Fund Name" HeaderStyle-CssClass="centre" ItemStyle-CssClass="centre"></asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Fund Risk Profile" HeaderText="Fund Risk Profile" HeaderStyle-CssClass="centre" ItemStyle-CssClass="centre"></asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Customer Name" HeaderText="Customer Name" HeaderStyle-CssClass="centre" ItemStyle-CssClass="centre"></asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Investment Date" HeaderText="Investment Date" HeaderStyle-CssClass="centre" ItemStyle-CssClass="centre"></asp:BoundColumn>

    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Years Held" HeaderStyle-CssClass="centre" ItemStyle-CssClass="centre">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Years" ID="txtUsYears"></asp:TextBox>
            <ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="filtertxtYears" runat="server"
                Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtUsYears" FilterType="Custom" ValidChars="0123456789"></ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>

    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Amount (£)" HeaderStyle-CssClass="centre" ItemStyle-CssClass="centre">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Amount"  ID="txtUsAmount"></asp:TextBox>
            <ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="filtertxtsAmount" runat="server"
                Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtUsAmount" FilterType="Custom" ValidChars=".-0123456789"></ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>

    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Switching to Product" HeaderStyle-CssClass="centre" ItemStyle-CssClass="centre">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" Width="200px" CssClass="centre ddlMoveToProduct" ID="ddlProduct">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>

    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Switching to Fund" HeaderStyle-CssClass="centre ddlMoveToFund" ItemStyle-CssClass="centre">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" Width="200px" CssClass="centre ddlFund" ID="ddlFund">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>

    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Switching to Amount (£)" HeaderStyle-CssClass="centre" ItemStyle-CssClass="centre">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Amount" ID="txtSwitchToAmount"></asp:TextBox>
            <ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="filtertxtSwitchToAmount" runat="server"
                Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtSwitchToAmount" FilterType="Custom" ValidChars=".-0123456789"></ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>

    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Switching to Lump Sum Amount (£)" HeaderStyle-CssClass="centre" ItemStyle-CssClass="centre">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control"  placeholder="Amount" ID="txtSwitchToLumpSumAmount"></asp:TextBox>
            <ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="filtertxtSwitchToLumpSumAmount" runat="server"
                Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtSwitchToLumpSumAmount" FilterType="Custom" ValidChars=".-0123456789"></ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>

</Columns>
```

Any and all help very much appreciated.

Thanks

Simon

Comment: Any specific reason use Jquery to populate drop down list? Otherwise do populate dropdown on page load. So you don't alter any server specific controls. ASP.Net used viewstate and also the web controls (dropdownlist in this case) are rendered to HTML with specific IDs to maintain the view state. Its not right to expect that web controls will work as usual after and altering server controls using jQuery or other frontend framework.

Comment: @Shiham I am using JQuery to add the options because it is being populated based on the response of a previous dropdown list in the same data grid.  If there is an easier way of populating it based on the selectedindex change event in the dropown list I would be happy to use that method.

Comment: I suggest to use ASP.Net UpdatePanel instead of using jquery to populate DropDownList. Place both dropdownlists inside update panel. Follow this post :) http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Populate-one-DropDownList-based-on-another-DropDownList-selected-value-in-ASPNet.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive found a working solution now,

```
Protected Sub ddlProduct_Change(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim ddl As DropDownList = DirectCast(sender, DropDownList)
    Dim rowdIdx = Convert.ToInt16(ddl.ClientID.Remove(0, ddl.ClientID.Length - 1))

    Dim ddlFund As DropDownList = CType(dgUnsuitableSwitch.Items(rowdIdx).Cells(0).FindControl("ddlUsFund"), DropDownList)

    Dim dt = GetFundsToMoveTo(ddl.SelectedValue)

    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        ddlFund.Items.Add(row(0).ToString())
    Next


End Sub
```